# Why doesnt this datatable filter data according to my search filter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am trying to search records based on inputs that the user puts from the text boxes in the table. It is not showing the records properly. Please help. I am trying to get the records in the onchange() of respective text-boxes however; its not working.

Here is my JSFiddle:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function () {
    var table = $("#datatable").DataTable();

    $('#search-id').on('change', function(){

        console.log("id called");

        table
        .column(1)
        .search(this.value)
        .draw();
    });

    $('#search-fname').on('change', function(){

        table
        .column(2)
        .search(this.value)
        .draw();
    });

    $('#search-lname').on('change', function(){

        table
        .column(3)
        .search(this.value)
        .draw();
    });

    $('#search-mobile').on('change', function(){

        table
        .column(4)
        .search(this.value)
        .draw();
    });

});
</script>
<table id="datatable" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
  <thead>
  <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" id="search-id" placeholder="Search ID"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="search-fname" placeholder="Search name"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="search-lname" placeholder="Search surnam"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="search-mobile" placeholder="Search mobile"></td>
                </tr>



    <tr>
      <th>Profile id</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Surname</th>
      <th>Mobile#</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>Profile id</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Surname</th>
      <th>Mobile#</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Keller</td>
      <td>18411564</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Donald</td>
      <td>Duck</td>
      <td>49816156</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/6p1jauLu/)

Answer (score 4):

Your code is working fine, the issue is because the column indexes are `0` based, so you're looking for the value in the wrong column, for example:

```
$('#search-id').on('change', function() {
    table
        .column(0) // id column == 0, not 1
        .search(this.value)
        .draw();
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/6p1jauLu/1/)

Also note that you can completely DRY up your code with the use of `data-*` attributes and a single event handler based on a class:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="text" class="search" data-column="0" placeholder="Search ID">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" class="search" data-column="1" placeholder="Search name">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" class="search" data-column="2" placeholder="Search surname">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" class="search" data-column="3" placeholder="Search mobile">
    </td>
</tr>
```

```js
var $table = $("#datatable").DataTable();
$('.search').on('keyup change', function() {
    $table
        .column($(this).data('column'))
        .search(this.value)
        .draw();
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/6p1jauLu/3/)

Comment: Even if I change it to 0,1,2,3 it doesnt work. Can you show me in the fiddle?

Comment: I understand the behavior. It doesnt show me the result till I dont move my control away from the textbox. What if I want to show the result as soon as the user stops typing?

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Answer (score 1):

You also will need to use a 'keyup' listener. Change only occurs in the text input fields when they lose focus.